# cellForNextPageAtIndexPath in swift

Tags: pagination

hello this is my code:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForNextPageAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> PFTableViewCell {


    let cell = PFTableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Subtitle, reuseIdentifier: "cell")

        cell.textLabel?.text = "Load more..."

    return cell

}

 override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {

    return 80
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.objects.count
}

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{

        let cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Subtitle, reuseIdentifier: "cell")
        cell.textLabel?.text = self.objects[indexPath.row]["RalleyName"] as? String
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = self.objects[indexPath.row]["UserName"] as? String

        return cell
}
```

the thing is that i don't know if im implementing correctly the forNextPageAtIndexPath because it just doesn't appear.

please help

Comment: I just described how to customize the custom cell here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31860990/cellfornextpageatindexpath-not-visible-in-swift2/33381883#33381883